# How to transform unstructured text to rdf turtle in practice?

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining, turtle-rdf, knowledge-graph

i am currently working on a study project, where i have to transform the vehicle complaints descriptions from the NHTSA Database (https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/nhtsas-office-of-defects-investigation-odi-complaints) into rdf-turtle and later into a Knowledge Graph representation maybe using GraphDB, etc. A set of descriptions can be found in the attachment.

I have research topics like NER, Relation Extration, OpenIE, FRED, Knowledge Graph Construction, RDFS, OWL and Ontologies in theory.

Now, i come to a point where i just don't know how to practically do it.

Can someone help me with it and guide me a little bit through it?
Where should i start and with what?

Thanks you very much,
Dennis

[Examples customer complaints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzQaL.png)

Answer (score 2):

Stanford CORE NLP has Open IE that can extract triples from the text.
https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.html

If you want to do it with python, look into Stanza
https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza.
It has an official python wrapper that fires up a JAVA-based CORE NLP server at the backend.